# Passing data from backend (nodejs) to frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dom

I have data in my database (MongoDB) and I am finding data from DB and saving it to array. And when button is clicked on page I want to send that data to my JavaScript file and using DOM show it on page.

I am finding data form DB when page loads:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ipsumTextArray = [];
    Ipsum.find({}, function(err, allIpsumTexts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            allIpsumTexts.forEach(function(ipsum) {
                ipsumTextArray.push(ipsum.text);
            });
        }
        res.render('home');
    });
});
```

And in my other JavaScript file I want this function to get data from DB and do whatever I want.

```
function randomIpsum(text) {
    text.value = 'text from database'; // text is textarea where I want to show text
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the data when you render the home page. Is this a server-rendered or single-page application, even? Are you expecting the client to make requests (where are those requests) or the server to build the whole page (why not use the data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render with a parameter.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ipsumTextArray = [];
    Ipsum.find({}, function(err, allIpsumTexts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            allIpsumTexts.forEach(function(ipsum) {
                ipsumTextArray.push(ipsum.text);
            });
        }
        res.render('home', { arr: ipsumTextArray });
    });
});
```

In the front-end (view):

```
var arr= {{ arr }}

function randomIpsum(text) {
    //text.value = 'text from database'; // text is textarea where I want to show text
    text.value = arr[0]
}
```

**OR**

You can send a plain text from your nodejs.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ipsumTextArray = [];
    Ipsum.find({}, function(err, allIpsumTexts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            allIpsumTexts.forEach(function(ipsum) {
                ipsumTextArray.push(ipsum.text);
            });
        }
        res.send(ipsumTextArray);
    });
});
```

You can get the data using jQuery in the front-end.

```
<button id="btn">Get Data</button>

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $.get("/", function(data){
        randomIpsum(text, data)
    })
})

function randomIpsum(text, data) {
    //text.value = 'text from database'; // text is textarea where I want to show text
    text.value = data
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response sir. When I am trying to do as you just wrote me to do I am getting those errors in my front-end file.
Property assignement expected.
Declaration of statement expected

Comment: @Tony There is a question, what is your client-side technology? nodejs view, react, or ...? And also I added the option into my answer.

Comment: I am using nodejs view. I prefer not to use jQuery so I would like you to fix if possible first option in your answer

Comment: Ok. How about this one: `<script>var arr= "<%= arr %>";</script>`

Comment: What is your template engine?

Comment: Is there any better way than: "Ok. How about this one: <script>var arr= "<%= arr %>";</script>" ?. My template engine is EJS.

Comment: No, for the EJS template engine, It is the standard way to get data from the server-side.